# What game do these dice belong to?

Tags: identify-this-game

I can't for the life of me can't remember where these dice came from, but I remember liking the game (it was from my childhood). Does anyone recognize where these came from?

[image]

Comment: Hi!  Welcome to the site.  Can you give us more information about the game?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Those are from Cosmic Wimpout, at http://www.cosmicwimpout.com/, and yes, that's a great game.